# Including a text file inside a jar file and reading it

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java resource as file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file)

I am kind of new to Java and I am trying to get a text file inside a Jar file.

At the moment when I execute my jar I have to have my text file in the same folder as the jar fil.  If the text file is not there I'll get a `NullPointerException`, which I want to avoid.

What I want to do is to get the txt file inside the jar so I wont have this problem.  I tried some guides but they didn't seem to work.  My current read function goes like this:

```
public static HashSet<String> readDictionary()
{
    HashSet<String> toRet = new HashSet<>();
     try
     {
            // Open the file that is the first 
            // command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Dictionary.txt");
        try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream)) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Read Lines
                toRet.add(strLine);
            }
        }
            return toRet;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
     } 
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't try to find a file as a "file" in a Jar file. Use resources instead.

Get a reference to the class or class loader and then on the class or class loader call `getResourceAsStream(/* resource address */);`.

---

See similar questions below (avoid creating new questions if possible):

- [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255)
- [How do I read a resource file from a Java jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256)
- [Accessing a file inside a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258244)
- [How to read a file from JAR archive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842306)

Answer (score 3):

```
// add a leading slash to indicate 'search from the root of the class-path'
URL urlToDictionary = this.getClass().getResource("/" + "Dictionary.txt");
InputStream stream = urlToDictionary.openStream();
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10450795/418556).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an exact duplicate of this question: [How do I access a config file inside the jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944610/how-do-i-access-a-config-file-inside-the-jar)

Further to your problem with `NullPointerException`, I suggest not to make sure it doesn't happen, but rather prepare for it and handle it properly. I'd go even further to ask you to *always* check your variables for null value, it's a good thing to do.