# Export runnable jar with eclipse

Tags: java, swing, jar, export

i have a program java swing program that reads a .txt file. When i try to make runnable jar file it cant read it. How can i make a runnable jar for such a program? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File -> Export -> Java -> Runnable JAR file

Make sure you are setting your launch configuration for the `.jar` file correctly, and that you are extracting the required libraries into the `.jar` as well.

The text file is probably not being pointed to the right location in your source code.  I would suggest looking into a `JFileChooser` and getting the location of the selected file from that. You could also have the text file pinpointed to one directory.  An example of this:

```
File dir = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA"), "folder");
if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) File file = new File(dir, "input.txt");
```

This code sets up a folder in the user's `AppData` folder on their computer (Windows). The file created afterwards is then put into that folder.  Using code like that, I can now read that file no matter where my `.jar` file is placed, as long as `input.txt` exists at that location.

Comment: FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
   DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
   String strLine;
   while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

Comment: Yep, with this code, `input.txt` always has to be at the same location that the `.jar` is located. See my updated answer for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks, i got it. However , cant i insert this txt inside of jar?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452825/including-a-text-file-inside-a-jar-file-and-reading-it) could help you out. Try doing a little research on your own. This was found pretty easily by me in less than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse go to file -> export -> java -> runnable jar file.

As for reading the .txt file, you can either hard code the file location in the code, or you can feed it in as argument through the command line, ie java myProgram.jar myFile.txt