# How to read a file from JAR archive?

Tags: java, jar

I need to read the content of `/test/a.xml` from a `test.jar` file (they are both variables, of course, not constants). What is the simplest way to do it?

```
File file = new File("test.jar");
String path = "/test/a.xml";
String content = // ... how?
```

Comment: Is your application also running from `test.jar`?

Comment: No, my application is not running from test.jar

Comment: Are you using Java 7?

Comment: You can try to adapt this example: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/javatip49/JarResources.java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
JarFile file = new JarFile(new File("test.jar"));
JarEntry entry = file.getJarEntry("/test/a.xml");
String content = IOUtils.toString(file.getInputStream(entry));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ZipInputStream` and search for your requested file.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
ZipInputStream zis =  new ZipInputStream(fis);
ZipEntry ze;

while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
   if(ze.getName().equals("/test/a.xml")
   {
       //use zis to read the file's content
   }
```

Comment: How to use zis to read the file's content?

Comment: @mendel when you're in that if you can use `fis` like a regular `InputStream` and it will give you the content of the file